# 'Couldn't find Game without an ID' when searching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, model-view-controller

I am trying to let a user search through an API but I'm getting the following error:

"Couldn't find Game without an ID"

Here is my controller:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @games = Game.all
  end

  def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)
  end

  def show
  end

  def search
    @games = Game.find(params[:id])
    game = GiantBomb::Game.name
  end

  def new
    @game = Game.new
  end

  def edit
  end

private

  def game_params
    params.require(:game).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :games
  root to: 'pages#home'
  post '/search', to: 'games#search', as: :search
end
```

I think it is unlikely that my search form is causing the error but here it is anyways:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
          <%= form_tag search_path class: "row", method: :get do %>
          <div class="col-12 col-sm pr-sm-0">
            <%= text_field_tag :game,
              params[:game],
              class: "form-control input-lg",
              id: "typed-text" %>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group-btn ml-3">
            <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
          <% end %>
```

Do I need to alter my routes or is there an issue with how I wrote the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're getting that error because `params[:id]` doesn't exist when you are reaching the `def search` method. Calling `.find` on something will always result in an exception being raised unless something is found. If this is intended then cool otherwise change it to `.find_by id: params[:id]`. This would cause your `@games` variable to be nil.

I think that you are trying to search on `params[:game]`. In which case you may have to use `@games = Game.find_by game: params[:game]`

You can see what params are being passed to your method in your logs.. but it may be worth attaching a debugger; such as `byebug` to the top of your method so you can see what params are present.